# How to set toolbar group on ckeditor5?

Tags: html, reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5, richtext

I want to put some toolbar items together with dropdown, how I do this?

```
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

   <CKEditor
        data={input.value}
        editor={ ClassicEditor }
        config={{         
          toolbar: ['heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'blockQuote', 'link', 'numberedList', 'bulletedList', 'imageUpload', 'insertTable',
            'tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells', 'mediaEmbed', '|', 'undo', 'redo']
        }}     
      />
```

I need 'bold' and 'italic' in a dropdown

Answer (score 0):

**You can see this code to understand the problem.**

```
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote' ],
        heading: {
            options: [
                { model: 'paragraph', title: 'Paragraph', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph' },
                { model: 'heading1', view: 'h1', title: 'Heading 1', class: 'ck-heading_heading1' },
                { model: 'heading2', view: 'h2', title: 'Heading 2', class: 'ck-heading_heading2' }
            ]
        }
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.log( error );
    } );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not,  I want this like toolbar: [ 'heading',  ['bold' , 'italic'], 'link' ]
                                                                     
'bold' and 'italic' in one dropdown.。  Not split with '|'